# N1QL accessing object keys with hyphens

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have an object in couchbase with uuid as its key.

```
  "user": {
    "f5ada4b8-cb68-4c85-a48d-87a1217963ca": [
      {
        "user_variant_id": false,
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want to access user['f5ada4b8-cb68-4c85-a48d-87a1217963ca']. But this notation does not work in N1QL select statement. Can someone help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this. The simplest way is to escape using back ticks, as suggested by @Evaldas:

```
`user`.`f5ada4b8-cb68-4c85-a48d-87a1217963ca`
```

Another approach is this (note the . before the left bracket):

```
`user`.["f5ada4b8-cb68-4c85-a48d-87a1217963ca"]
```